# CSS is not loading properly when refreshing page in Angular 8

Tags: angular

In my angular application, I have 2 routes - `/login and /dashboard`.

If I navigate from login to dashboard route CSS is loading properly in the dashboard screen.
[image]

If I do refresh in the dashboard (or directly opens dashboard route) some of the CSS is not loading properly.

[image]

I checked in `Console and Network` tabs. I didn't get any errors and warnings.

I need your help to resolve this issue.

Comment: That sounds very strange indeed. Where is the missing css coming from? Is it in you component.css file or is it somewhere else? Are you using a preprocessor like scss? You should paste in the relevant code.

Comment: Yes, I am using the .scss file.

Comment: CSS is loading from global styles. After refreshing particular CSS style is not applying.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm currently facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check once if you have imported your CSS file in the angular.json file

Comment: build:{"options": {
           ...
            "styles": [
             
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
}

Yes. I am loading CSS file in angular.json file.